# Spark Master node on AWS can not pull data from external resources

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a standalone Spark cluster setup on AWS. 
I have pyspark programs that run as expected on my local machine. When I use spark-submit to submit the job to the Master node on AWS, everything seems to be fine until the moment I must pull some data from S3.

This is log I get on the Master GUI for the job I submit

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/08/11 16:23:04 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 8911@ip-10-32-3-4
16/08/11 16:23:04 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/08/11 16:23:04 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/08/11 16:23:04 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/08/11 16:23:04 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/08/11 16:23:04 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark,kasra
16/08/11 16:23:04 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark,kasra
16/08/11 16:23:04 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/08/11 16:23:04 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/08/11 16:23:04 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark, kasra); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark, kasra); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$onFailure$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds
    ... 8 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: TransportClient has not yet been set.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RpcOutboxMessage.onTimeout(Outbox.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$ask$1.applyOrElse(NettyRpcEnv.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$ask$1.applyOrElse(NettyRpcEnv.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onFailure$1.apply(Future.scala:138)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onFailure$1.apply(Future.scala:136)
```

Based on the above log, it appears to me the access of Master to S3 is somehow being filtered

The code snippet behind this is

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", '...')
        sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", '...')
config_dict = {"fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId":"...",
       "fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey":"..."}

rdd = sc.hadoopFile('s3n://kasra.districtm.ca/SEGMENTS/SMALL_CSV/aa',
            'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat',
            'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
            'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
            conf=config_dict)
```

Note: using spark 2

Comment: Executors do the job and they load data from S3, not the master. It appears your cluster is not working properly, mainly from `Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout`. Your master couldn't talk to executors. You may want to verify that by doing simpler things like `sc.parallelize([1,2,3]).count()`

Comment: Thank you. I figured what the problem was. The access to S3 was not the issue. The issue was that I had not set the ip address of the spark driver host.

The issue was resolved by adding:

`conf = (SparkConf().set("spark.driver.host","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")) `

Note: if you are behind vpn, you must make sure you use the ip that spark master node is trying to use to talk to your local computer.